# Border-box VS content-box, Which is better to reset in reset css?

Tags: css, reset, box-sizing

As we know, Bootstrap sets the  border-box as the value of box-sizing in reset.css. But the default value of box-sizing is content-box. And in my current usage, I always use the default value because of the rule-convention over configuration. Which would you prefer?  Please share your reason, thank you.

Comment: In most cases border-box makes more sense. I have never seen cases when `content-box` was a preferred, it makes styling more confusing and usually makes box grow beyond sizes you expect.

Comment: There are elements where the default sizing is border-box though, so you have a good reason to reset it, no matter what to.

Comment: @ Mr Lister Could you list some elements?

Comment: @Jamter `select` springs to mind. There were others, but apparently those have been recognised as bugs, and corrected. `hr` was one, but only in Firefox, until recently.